# Ansible in Vagrantfile – pull playbook from git

Tags: git, vagrant, ansible

I have 3 git repos:

1. ansible config (roles, tasks...)
2. backend code
3. frontend code

In my Vagrantfile, I can specify a path to a playbook.

But what if I want to have the Ansible playbook pulled automatically from git? Can vagrant do that? I don't want to have duplicate Ansible configurations.

Or should I add my ansible repo as a submodule? Or something else?

Comment: Vagrantfiles are basically just Ruby code, so you can do pretty much anything and only your imagination is your limit. However, some Ruby knowledge required. Submodules would be simpler.

Comment: I would recommend a submodule as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have several similar situations to you.  Here's what I do...

All three repos sit in the same parent directory.

```
./parent
  |-- ansible
  |-- backend
  +-- frontend
```

I use the [vagrant-triggers](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) plugin to trigger updates to the ansible repo when I execute `vagrant up` or `vagrant provision`.  So the beginning of my `Vagrantfile` might look like

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.trigger.before :up do
    system("../ansible/update.sh")
  end
```

where `../ansible/update.sh` is a script that checks to make sure the ansible git repo is up-to-date and in the correct state (on the right branch, etc).

The next part then would be if you want the backend and frontend repos to be able to bootstrap themselves if the ansible repo doesn't exist.  And that just takes extra shell scripting with the vagrant-triggers plugin.  Also, if you prefer, you can use ansible's `local_action` (see [docs](https://docs.ansible.com/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation-rolling-updates-and-local-actions)) instead of shell scripts.

Comment: Looks like a good solution. I could use this for submodules as well, since they don't update automatically.